# Manipulating flag type in GetOptions from Getopt::Long

Tags: perl, getopt

Is there a way to turn off flags if they are enabled by default in `GetOptions`?

This is what I want:

- `-verbose 0` turns off verbosity
- `-verbose 1` turns on  verbosity
- `-verbose`   turns on  verbosity

Current code (from [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)):

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $data = "file.dat";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose = 1;
GetOptions ("length=i" => \$length,   # numeric
            "file=s"   => \$data,     # string
            "verbose"  => \$verbose)  # flag
or die("Error in command line arguments\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little too complex, but you can use an [optional value](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-values) combined with a [custom subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Getopt::Long;

sub make_handler {
    my $verbose = shift;

    return sub {
        my ($opt_name, $opt_value) = @_;

        die "$opt_name must be 0 or 1" if $opt_value !~ /^(?:0|1)?$/;

        if ($opt_value eq '') {
            $$verbose = 1;
        }
        else {
            $$verbose = $opt_value;
        }
    }
}

my $verbose = 1;
my $handler = make_handler(\$verbose);

GetOptions("verbose:s"  => $handler) or die "Error in command line arguments";

say $verbose;
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./foo 
1
$ ./foo --verbose
1
$ ./foo --verbose 0
0
$ ./foo --verbose 1
1
$ ./foo --verbose bar
verbose must be 0 or 1 at ./foo line 15.
Error in command line arguments at ./foo line 29.
```

Note that I used a closure to avoid global variables, since `Getopt::Long` doesn't do anything with the return value of custom subroutines and doesn't allow you to pass in the variable you want to set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `-noverbose` option satisfies my need.

Comment: @Jean That makes more sense. FWIW, I've never seen a command-line program that was verbose by default...usually there's both a `--verbose` option to show more than normal output and a `--quiet` option to show *no* output. For command line options, you should generally adhere to the principle of least surprise and follow common conventions.

Comment: Verbose was just an example. I am doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the way you describe, but the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#A-little-bit-less-simple-options) describes "negatable options" designated by an exclamation mark that let you do this:

```
my $verbose = 1; # default on
GetOptions ('verbose!' => \$verbose);
```

This allows `--verbose` (sets it to 1) or `--noverbose` (sets it to 0).

Answer (score 1):

The [Summary of Option Specifications](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Summary-of-Option-Specifications) in the documentation for [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) indicates that you could *almost* use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
my $data = "file.dat";
my $length = 24;
my $verbose = 1;
GetOptions ("length=i"  => \$length,   # numeric
            "file=s"    => \$data,     # string
            "verbose:i" => \$verbose)  # optional integer
or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

# Debugging/testing
print "Verbose = $verbose\n";
print "Options:\n";
for my $opt (@ARGV) { print "    $opt\n"; }
```

The `:` indicates that the value is optional, and the `i` indicates it takes an integer.

Sample runs (I called the script `gol.pl`):

```
$ perl gol.pl
Verbose = 1
Options:
$ perl gol.pl --verbose 0
Verbose = 0
Options:
$ perl gol.pl --verbose=0
Verbose = 0
Options:
$ perl gol.pl --verbose 1
Verbose = 1
Options:
$ perl gol.pl --verbose gooseberry
Verbose = 0
Options:
    gooseberry
$ perl gol.pl --verbose
Verbose = 0
Options:
$
```

There's an *'almost'* at the top.  As [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) correctly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131686/manipulating-flag-type-in-getoptions-from-getoptlong/29132126?noredirect=1#comment46490121_29132126), this sets `$verbose` to zero when the argument is omitted, which is not what you want.

Your interface is curious.  Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with:

```
--verbose    # Enables verbose mode
--noverbose  # Disables verbose mode
```

You can then use `"verbose!"` to handle that.  Also, since `verbose` mode is enabled by default, there's really no need to support `--verbose`; there's point in having `--verbose 0` to turn it off, or `--noverbose`, and maybe point in allowing `--verbose 9` for extra verbose, etc.  You need to think about whether your design is truly appropriate.

Comment: This is what I had, but `gol.pl --verbose` will set `$verbose` to 0, not 1 as the OP requested.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Good point - I missed that in the 'gooseberry' test.  I'll add some notes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `-noverbose` option satisfies my need.